# Rename uploaded file in joomla

Tags: joomla, upload, rename

I am new to Joomla, but i cannot seem to find a way to manually change the name of an uploaded file... please tell me how, if it is possible... i am a WordPress guy !

Do I have to install something more, because now, the only option I have is DELETE !

Comment: User uploaded?  FTP Uploaded?  How did you get this into Joomla?
If it's user uploaded from a form - check the component you've used for forms (Chronoforms is something I highly recommend) - they allow you the option to rename uploaded images IIRC.  But if you're talking about a photo you just uploaded through the media manager, you could just go in via FTP and rename whatever file you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This capability is not supported in the built in media manager, but there are other options like [jsmallfib](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/8570)

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post but it may help someone in future,

using joomla uploader just need to change like below.

```
    $file = JRequest::getVar('attachment', null, 'files', 'array');//attachment is the file type name in your html   
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
    $src = $file['tmp_name'];
    $dst = JPATH_SITE . DS . "images" . DS . 'archive'. DS. 'your_new_file_name'.JFile::getExt($filename);
     if ( JFile::upload($src, $dest) ){
       echo 'Uploaded';
     }
    else{
           echo 'Failed';
     }
```

Hope it helps someone..